# IPhone camera aspect ratio and saving scale and size

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am saving an iphone picture taken with my camera for an app I am creating:

```
    float w = photo.size.width;
    float h = photo.size.height;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,300,400);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size );
    [photo drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *picture1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *photoData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture1);
```

The float numbers are always:

```
 w = 2448
 h = 3264
```

Is this the aspect ratio for all iphone photos on all the devices?

Comment: I think not but you should check the device specifications. Anyway even if they are the same now they may not be in few months or whenever for what we know. If I remember correctly you can set the quality of the image received from the camera which changes both in size and aspect ratio. Try not to assume anything when dealing with such data if possible. If for some reason you do need a specific ratio/size you should do a check and resample the image in your code when needed. Maybe in time the picker controller will have an option to make a panorama which changes the size and ratio greatly...

Comment: if you got this resolved don't be shy and post an answer: it seems that I need to scale the images from camera->avfoundation by about 4% on iphones 5 and 6 (but not ipads). Or so our QA has found. I would hate to hack it in such an ugly way adding a by device switch to calculate the correction ratio